# Is it possible to enable versioning for the survey list in Sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to enable versioning for the survey list using CSOM, but it is throwing an error like value does not fall within the range. Is it possible to enable versioning for the survey list in Sharepoint online?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my knowledge, the survey list does not support historical versions, we can't enable versioning for the survey list using CSOM.